# java docBuilder java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a `xml file` by using the following code:

```
HistoryFileLocation = "\\22-srv-12\\users\\myusername\\.randomFolder\\Hello.xml";

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(HistoryFileLocation); <--- Exception is on this line
```

By using the above code i get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\22-srv-12\USERS\myusername\Desktop\22-srv-12\USERS\myusername\.randomFolder\Hello.xml (The file could not be found)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at im.Client$History.addMessage(Client.java:7006)
    at im.Client$ListenFromServer.run(Client.java:5435)
```

For some reason the path i specify is ignored? Seems like java is adding more folders that i did not specify?

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it might be trying to construct a relative path - perhaps you could pass in your path relative to the base

Comment: Its strange because the path that I've specified exists, and the path that java somehow adds does not

Comment: are you showing the good code ? in your code HistoryFileLocation is about Hello.xml and the stacktrace about History.xml

Comment: @Alosyius try `HistoryFileLocation = "..\\.randomFolder\\Hello.xml";`

Comment: Updated, i had renamed it for the purpose of the question. Problem however is that it tried to add some strange path before the one i specifiy

Comment: @krsteeve it still tries to add stuff: `\\22-srv-12\USERS\ myusername\Desktop\..\22-srv-12\users\ myusername\. randomFolder\Hello.xml`

Comment: @Alosyius The reason it is "adding stuff" is because its constructing a path relative to the `Desktop` folder.

Comment: The application is running in a very locked down environment it has to choose exactly the path that I've specified or else it wont be able to read/write

Comment: Where is application running from, relative to `22-srv-12`? Maybe show your file Structure

Comment: Its running here `\\22-srv-12\USERS\myusername\Desktop`